# Filters in Mainpanel Horizontally

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build Rshiny app, i have 3 tabs, but my problem is in the first one, I have 2 filters for this page "Country" and "Package" and i want to show in the top of main panel both filters but horizontally, i mean, Package should be in the right part of Country filter, How can i modify my current code to show both filters in one line?, Thanks !!
[image: this are my current filters]

```
shinyAppui <- tagList(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  navbarPage(
    title = "Alternative Risk Transfer - Parametric Weather Solutions",
    id = "navbar",
    
    
    
    tabPanel(title="Map",
             value= "_map",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel( width = NULL, height = NULL
                 # Filter for country
                 # pickerInput(inputId = "country_", label = strong("     Select Country"),
                 #             choices = unique(Stations_static$Country), "Labels",
                 #             options = list(`live-search` = TRUE)),
                 # 
                 # # Filter for package
                 # uiOutput("data_filtered_country")
                 # 
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 pickerInput(inputId = "country_", label = strong("     Select Country"),
                             choices = unique(Stations_static$Country), "Labels",
                             options = list(`live-search` = TRUE), inline = TRUE),
                 uiOutput("data_filtered_country"),
                 
                 leafletOutput("map_stations",width="150%",height="550px"),
                 DT::DTOutput("table_map",width="150%",height="550px")
               )),
             fluidRow(
               style = "border-top: 1px solid; border-color: #A9A9A9; padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;",
               column(width = 8),
               column(width = 2),
               column(
                 width = 2,
                 style = "padding-left: 0px;",
                 actionButton(
                   inputId = "showTabRiskQuantification",
                   label = "Static data updated as of June 2020",
                   width = '100%'
                 )
               )
             )
    ), # ends tab panel
```

Comment: `fluidRow(column(6,pickerInput(…)),column(6,uiOutput()))`  should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @YBS said in the comment when you want to place objects in the same row you should use the `fluidRow(column(),column(),...)` structure. This will make your dashboard responsive as well. In this case it would look like this.

```
fluidRow(
 column(
   width = 3,
   pickerInput(inputId = "country_", label = strong("     Select Country"),
               choices = unique(Stations_static$Country), "Labels",
               options = list(`live-search` = TRUE), inline = TRUE)
 ),
 column(
   width = 3,
   uiOutput("data_filtered_country")
 )
)
```

where you can play around with different values for width to get the spacing you want.